# Limit of a sequence in a product sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Given $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n} = 0$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_n = \infty$.

Suppose $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_k \cdot g_k = M < \infty$.

[EDIT after Mark's reply]: Additional assumption of $g_n \geq 0$. What can we say about~$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g_{n}$? Does the limit always exist? Is it always finite?

Comment: Let $f_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $g_{n} = (-1)^{n}$. Then $\sum f_n = \infty$ and $\sum f_{n} \cdot g_{n} = \ln(2)$ even though $\lim g_{n}$ does not exist.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks. Is there a way to say when $\lim g_{n}$ exists and is finite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the limit may not exist, even if we impose $g_n>0$. Consider $f_n=1/n$ and
$$
g_n=\begin{cases}1/n & \text{if }n\text{ is not a square,}\\
1 & \text{if }n\text{ is a square.}\end{cases}
$$
$$
\sum f_n\,g_n=\sum_{n\text{ not a square}}\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty.
$$

Comment: Nice, thanks. For the example of $g_n$ you gave, how does one show $\sum_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n g_n = M < \infty$?

Comment: It is bounded by twice the sum of $1/n^2$.